# How do I tell which wires are Red/Positive and Black/Negative on these fans?

Tags: power, soldering, wire, fan

thank you for taking the time to answer this question :
Here are the fans in question... I only ask because I burnt both fans trying to find the right wires, so I guess I put the wrong wires on for too long?

[image]
[image]
**And this fan as well, if you can: [image]

**Is there anything I do with my multi-meter to see which wires are the Red/Black or Pos/Neg so I can correctly position my connections**, or is there an electronic handyman's way to do it without burning the fans, is it just you try all combinations but quickly so that I don't burn the motor? There are 16 combinations and that is 16 chances to burn the motor.

OR

I will look for a guide on these models?

Comment: The first thing to do is always to look for documentation or guides. (And that is the electronic handyman's way.) If you have to reverse engineer it, either open it up and study the details, or hook it up to a low voltage which is current limited, start experimenting, and hope you don't blow anything up before you've extracted the information you need.

Comment: Get a manufacturers sheet on the fans.  And if there really are 16 combinations, and 16 chances to 'burn the motor', then there are 0 combinations that won't 'burn the motor'.  Do you even know what kind of motors you have?

Answer (score 1):

A quick search does not bring up this particular series on the Delta website. That said, this is a 4-wire DC brushless fan and there are some good resources available on understanding how these are wired up and controlled.

The typical wiring pattern for these fans is GND/12V/SENSE/CONTROL. Finding the ground wire should be easy enough with your multimeter.

Take a look at these websites if you want to learn more. Perhaps someone with direct experience on these fans can chime in.

http://pcbheaven.com/wikipages/How_PC_Fans_Work/
http://www.hardwaresecrets.com/anatomy-of-computer-fans/2/

Comment: How can I find the ground wire using my multimeter if I don't plug it into a power source? I am a beginner I really don't know. Also, how do I know what position the "4 pin head" should be in: I mean like, how would I know if I have the 4 pin flipped upside down so that when I follow the GND/12V/SENSE/CONTROL model I properly align the wires to the representation?

Comment: To find your GND, check for continuity between each wire and the fan chassis. Once you have found the GND, the other pins will become obvious (there's only one direction to go).

Comment: I am not sure I follow Minho, continuity? Is that an electrical term? I am really new to electronics so if you could give me a picture of something that would be great.

Comment: "Check for continuity" = "measure resistance" - a low resistance (probably under 1 Ohm) between a wire and the chassis would indicate that the wire is connected to the chassis, so is "Ground".  Many meters have a "continuity test" function where the meter will beep if there is a low resistance between the probes.

Answer (score 0):

If you took it out of a laptop, you can always measure the voltage on the connector on the laptop's motherboard where the fan was connected.

Comment: I did not take it out of the laptop :(